# jQplot tooltip dismiss issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have implemented a simple bar chart,

ive added tooltip feature using highlighter but i am facing an issue with the same.

When i move the mouse down and exit the chart canvas the tooltip doesnt dismiss

[image]

I have tried adding

```
 $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotMouseMove', handleMove]);
 $.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotMouseLeave', handleMove]);
```

But it doesnt work , i get the error **handleMove is not defined**

Here is the code fiddle for the same

**https://jsfiddle.net/9j2na3L7/**

Comment: solved below :) please mark as solved and +1 the answer if it was helpful. And thank you for jsfiddle, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this working :)

**-- PROBLEM:**

- *Mouse cursor escaping too fast from canvas, prevents event form fireing*

**-- SOLUTION**:

**First of all grab a handle of `jplot` object**

`var plotBar = $.jqplot('task_brk_bar_chart', [...`

So we can use it to manipulate it on run-time.

**Then we will use `jqplotDataHighlight` and `jqplotDataUnHighlight` events to change the graph properties and `replot()` function to apply them on fly.**

```
$('#task_brk_bar_chart').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function () {
    plotBar.showTooltip = true;
    plotBar.replot();
});
$('#task_brk_bar_chart').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function () {
    plotBar.showTooltip = false;
    plotBar.repolot();
});
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/urahara/9j2na3L7/1/

Note: Copy your old `css` to override my setting, it was for testing purposes only.

Cheers!